# jQuery Content Slide (works but looking for a more simple solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below works as it should, but i was wondering if there was a more simplified code i could use for all those if statements, perhaps calling a single function? I tried that, but obviously i need to skip the one if statement depending on which button is pressed. Any thoughts or comments are welcome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Slide_IN</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content_home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width:80%;
    color:#96C;
    top:200px;
}

#content_about {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width:80%;
    color:#FF6633;
    top:200px;
}

#content_folio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width:80%;
    color:#CC0000;
    top:200px;
}

#content_contact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width:80%;
    color:#9C0;
    top:200px;
}
</style>
<script>

$(function(){
    $(".home").click(function() {
        if($('#content_about').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_about").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_about').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_folio').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_folio").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_folio').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_contact').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_contact").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_contact').removeAttr('style')});
        }

        $("#content_home").animate({'left':'10%'}, "slow");
    });

    $(".about").click(function() {
        if($('#content_home').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_home").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_home').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_folio').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_folio").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_folio').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_contact').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_contact").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_contact').removeAttr('style')});
        }

        $("#content_about").animate({'left':'10%'}, "slow");
    });

    $(".folio").click(function() {
        if($('#content_home').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_home").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_home').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_about').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_about").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_about').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_contact').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_contact").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_contact').removeAttr('style')});
        }

        $("#content_folio").animate({'left':'10%'}, "slow");
    });

    $(".contact").click(function() {
        if($('#content_home').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_home").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_home').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_about').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_about").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_about').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_folio').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_folio").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_folio').removeAttr('style')});
        }
        if($('#content_contact').css("left") == '10%'){
            $("#content_contact").animate({'left':'-100%'}, "slow", function(){$('#content_contact').removeAttr('style')});
        }

        $("#content_contact").animate({'left':'10%'}, "slow");
    });
});



</script>
</head>

<body>
<a class="home" href="#index">Home</a><br>
<a class="about" href="#about">About</a><br>
<a class="folio" href="#folio">Portfolio</a><br>
<a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
<div style="" id="content_home"> HOME Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lorem dui, consequat in malesuada et, varius rutrum nunc. Duis consequat, felis non convallis hendrerit, turpis enim mattis lacus, id bibendum arcu orci sit amet arcu. Sed lobortis, mi ac varius semper, lorem ante laoreet justo, vel mollis ante massa vitae lacus. Praesent quis ipsum libero. Donec in nulla ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Sed et nibh est, a suscipit urna. Nunc hendrerit dolor vel eros ultrices dapibus semper odio elementum. Vivamus et quam ut eros venenatis volutpat nec in velit. Proin sed nisl non nulla vulputate aliquam sit amet et ipsum.
</div>
<div style="" id="content_about"> ABOUT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lorem dui, consequat in malesuada et, varius rutrum nunc. Duis consequat, felis non convallis hendrerit, turpis enim mattis lacus, id bibendum arcu orci sit amet arcu. Sed lobortis, mi ac varius semper, lorem ante laoreet justo, vel mollis ante massa vitae lacus. Praesent quis ipsum libero. Donec in nulla ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Sed et nibh est, a suscipit urna. Nunc hendrerit dolor vel eros ultrices dapibus semper odio elementum. Vivamus et quam ut eros venenatis volutpat nec in velit. Proin sed nisl non nulla vulputate aliquam sit amet et ipsum.
</div>
<div style="" id="content_folio"> PORTFOLIO Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lorem dui, consequat in malesuada et, varius rutrum nunc. Duis consequat, felis non convallis hendrerit, turpis enim mattis lacus, id bibendum arcu orci sit amet arcu. Sed lobortis, mi ac varius semper, lorem ante laoreet justo, vel mollis ante massa vitae lacus. Praesent quis ipsum libero. Donec in nulla ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Sed et nibh est, a suscipit urna. Nunc hendrerit dolor vel eros ultrices dapibus semper odio elementum. Vivamus et quam ut eros venenatis volutpat nec in velit. Proin sed nisl non nulla vulputate aliquam sit amet et ipsum.
</div>
<div style="" id="content_contact"> CONTACT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lorem dui, consequat in malesuada et, varius rutrum nunc. Duis consequat, felis non convallis hendrerit, turpis enim mattis lacus, id bibendum arcu orci sit amet arcu. Sed lobortis, mi ac varius semper, lorem ante laoreet justo, vel mollis ante massa vitae lacus. Praesent quis ipsum libero. Donec in nulla ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Sed et nibh est, a suscipit urna. Nunc hendrerit dolor vel eros ultrices dapibus semper odio elementum. Vivamus et quam ut eros venenatis volutpat nec in velit. Proin sed nisl non nulla vulputate aliquam sit amet et ipsum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/janey/LnDsE/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your classes .about,.contact,.folio

try as single line function start

```
$(".about,.contact,.folio").click(){}
```

Please share if you have the same in jsfiddle demo working.

Comment: Your suggestion makes them all run at once.
Here is working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/janey/LnDsE/1/

Here is fiddle with your suggestion : http://jsfiddle.net/janey/wXeCH/